# Cmd+Tab switches to the correct space, but doesn't bring app up to front

Tags: macos

I have a problem (bug?) with application switching on Lion.

I use two Spaces. Say one has Postbox open, and another has Firefox and Vim.

Vim is in the foreground, and Firefox's window is behind it.

When I Cmd+Tab from Postbox to Firefox, the space is switched correctly, but Firefox remains in the background.

If I Cmd+Tab to Firefox again, or select it in the Dock, the window comes up front normally.

The bug isn't limited to Firefox only, seen it with many apps.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Timely. I *just* noticed this happening on my 10.7.3 machine today. Can't say I've ever noticed it before. It's intermittent. Sometimes Cmd-Tab will bring up the app, other times it's still not in the foreground after switching to the space.

Comment: Fullscreen applications don't seem to be affected by this, so my work around is to fullscreen as many of the applications as possible. I prefer the fullscreen version of applications (in most cases) so it doesn't bother me, but can appreciate that this work around wont be suitable for everyone. Using this work around I can switch between applications with command + tab or I can use the 4 finger swipe gesture on the trackpad without problem.

Comment: It does not happen on OSX 10.9 Mavericks, so probably they've fixed it.

Comment: Nope, this UX issue is still present on Mavericks.

Comment: Same thing happens to me when switching between Sublime Text and Chrome. Chrome menubar comes up but window is still hidden.

Comment: Turning on and off swoosh http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101574/prevent-switching-workspaces-when-clicking-on-dock-icon?rq=1

Comment: Still exists on macOS Sierra

Comment: There's a workaround - use the Bring All To Front command.
You can add command hotkeys in the Keyboard settings. You'll then have to Cmd+Tab to the app and then click the <bring-all-to-front-key>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To the original poster, you weren't doing anything wrong.

Whether it was intended as a feature or not, it is clearly a usability issue, aka a bug. The problem is that often the affected app window was left stacked on top of all other windows, *not* behind them. Upon switching back and forth with <strike>Spaces</strike> Mission Control, the app often gets stuck under other open windows.

The finger-twisting CMD-TAB-OPTION-release fails more often than not: it either doesn't do anything differently or it is impossible to accomplish due to autorepeating keys, making it a worthless gesture.

It is definitely a bug, not a feature. Keep flipping back and forth with CMD-TAB, and the window will pop back to the top, then drop down again, erratically.

Oh, it doesn't appear to affect Spaces, so it seems to be a regression.

Comment: Note: since the application is selected, you can also hit CMD-Backtick to find the window pane that should have been in the foreground. It is at least a less finger-fumbling gesture.

Comment: 581.95B in market cap, you would think they'd be able to pay the bugs to go away. I like @nacious 's answer. Full screen all apps seems to be the only way to make it reliable.

Comment: Has this been fixed yet? What's the best way to file a bug with Apple engineering?

Comment: Hard to believe but, this citation bolsters this answer [CMD + Tab will switch to the app you want, the problem is that often times even though you have switched to the app, it does not bring the window for that app to the front (which seems totally pointless) so you have to press CMD + TAB + OPTION buttons...](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252614849?answerId=254932434022#254932434022)

Answer (score 22):

It's a feature not a bug :-)

Start tabbing with <kbd>Cmd-Tab</kbd> until you get to the application you want to switch to, then press and hold <kbd>Option</kbd> before releasing <kbd>Cmd-Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Are you sure? If I put Skype in front of Sparrow on space 2, switch to Chrome in Space 1 and the Cmd-Tab to Sparrow *sometimes* it comes up in the foreground, *sometimes* it stays behind Skype. I just figured it was Skype. I blame most of the world's problems on Skype though...

Comment: Atleast in Yosemite, using **option** seems to be required only if the app was minimized before. And so, it might be a more efficient to just hide (**command** + **H**) windows and not minimize them so that they can be navigated to through **command** + **tab**

Comment: So you are saying I press Cmd-Tab all way to see a minimized window?

Comment: Why do I need to press three key (or combination) to open a hidden window? How is it a feature?? You don't know the window is hidden or not, because there is no sign in cmd+tab view.

Comment: thanks for the answer, and if it is a feature then can we turn it off ?

Comment: FYI you can let go of Tab before you push Option to make it sightly easier on twisting your fingers around, but make sure you let go of Cmd before you let go of Option.  
(So that's Cmd+Tab to get to your app, then let go of Tab, then push Option, then let go of Command, then let go of Option.  Ugh).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with jerseyboy, it is pretty much a bug.  So, under Lion 10.7.3, in mail, I switch to safari, which is in a different space.  Then I switch back to mail, and the space duly switches to where I was.  However, the window that was previously on top is now hidden behind terminal and a few other windows I have open on that space.  This is an annoying interference in rapid switching between applications.

One slightly less awkward approach to get the application back to the front again is to cmd-tab to the application in question, release (which switches to the right space), and then hit cmd-tab cmd-shift-tab (faking a switch to another application but actually going back to the same one).  This sequence is really awkward being 3 combos when one ought to be enough.  Come on Apple, at least let us select this behavior in system prefs or a mysterious plist command line thingy.

Answer (score 3):

[KeyRemap4Macbook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) allows remapping <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to <kbd>command<kbd>+</kbd>tab<kbd>+</kbd>option</kbd>, if you want this to be the default behavior. It also has some very cool/powerful customizations like remapping keyboard shortcuts only for specific applications - e.g. remap <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> in Firefox to <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to switch between browser tabs.

Comment: the app is called Karabiner and the option to tick is under Change Key ->Change Command_L Key(Left Command) ->Command_L to Option_L (Pass-Through Command+Tab)

Comment: but program messes up copy, paste, cut,.. shortcuts

Comment: I'm keen to make command+tab+option the default behaviour without having to press the option key.  I have Karabiner, but I'm unable to set up a configuration so that command+tab will be mapped to command+tab+option.  Has anyone been successful with this?  I tried looking for @M.C. 's suggestion however couldn't work out the "pass-through command+tab".