# Prevent switching workspaces when clicking on dock icon

Tags: macos, dock, spaces

I am constantly running multiple applications on multiple workspaces. I want to remain on the same workspace, and only switch workspaces when I explicitly ask for it (e.g. with a magic mouse gesture).

Currently when I click on the app icon in the dock, osx switches to the next workspace that has a window of the active application.

I know there is an option in System Preferences -> Misson Control, called *"When switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for the application"*. What it does: When clicking on the icon of an **inactive** application, don't switch to a workspace that has the application window. But this option **does not affect** the behaviour of clicking on an **active** application.

---

The question: **How do I prevent OSX from ever switching to another wokspace when clicking on an app icon in the dock,** regardless of whether the app is active of inactive?

Comment: Do you have a fix for MacOS Sierra? This doesn't seem to work anymore...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For **macOS 10.11 El Capitan** and earlier **only**:

Open `Terminal.app`, then run the following commands.

Change the default workspace preference:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool NO
```

Next, restart the Dock with this command:

```
killall Dock
```

References:
[How can I disable auto-switching desktops?](https://discussions.apple.com/message/21918357#21918357)
[Disable Space switching on Command-Tab](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2008021122525348)

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution also disables the swtiching from any other dock action, like application exposé view or the right-click full application window list. Nonetheless, I like it much more. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn’t work in MacOS 10.12 (Sierra) and later versions.

Comment: This does not work on Catalina

Answer (score 4):

Unlike the original questioner, I was trying to **enable this effect**. I wanted to switch between spaces where applications lived on different desktops.

I just took a guess at:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool TRUE
```

and

```
killall Dock
```

The two commands above worked like a charm to restore the effect.

Comment: Still not working on MacOS Sierra 10.12 and later versions...

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is a relevant setting in later versions of MacOS when using the app switcher (cmd+tab), but that doesn't work when clicking on the app icon in the Dock (so it doesn't solve the OPs question):

System Preferences > Mission Control > "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application"

Comment: This does not solve the problem

Comment: @MichaelSchmid It works for me on Catalina if I use the app switcher (cmd+tab), but you're right that it doesn't work when clicking on the icon in the Dock.